# Spring security: Implement JWT Filter

Tags: spring-security

Landing on Spring security is really an stucky path.

I need to implement an authentication mechanism in order to pick jwt token and extract authentication.

It's really complicated to be sure whether I'm using best approach in order to implement it.

I need to implement and `JWTAuthenticationFilter`

Questions:

- Why do I need to extend from `BasicAuthenticationFilter`? All exemples over there extends from it to implement a `JWTAuthenticationFilter`! What does it have to do with BASIC mechanism?
- Also I saw over there `JWTAuthorizationFilter`. Why `...AuthorizationFilter` instead of `...AuthenticationFilter`?

Which is the best approach about to get my goal?

Comment: best approach is to read the spring security documentation on JWTs and not google outdated tutorials https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide a custom filter for that, you can use [`spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` dependency and configure Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html), like so:

```java
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://idp.example.com/issuer
```

By doing this, Spring Security will go to the identity provider and retrieve the JWT keys to validate the token provided in the request. If you need to customize the behavior you can override Spring Boot auto-configuration, see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-sansboot).

Comment: The problem is that, deployment architecture solution is a bit tricky. There's no an external idp issuer. Can I configure idp and resourceserver inside a the same service?

Comment: You can override Spring Boot auto-configuration as I mentioned and provide a bean of type `JwtDecoder` that validates the JWT the way you want, like `NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(...)` or `NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(...)`, or even your own implementation of that.